Stm32h743 write protect, Bootloader lock and RDP
I am trying to understand how you can lock an Stm32h743 so it can't accept unauthorized firmware while having physical access to it via USB and BOOT0 pin is tied to ground (meaning it always boots to dfu).
I am fully aware of the "secure boot" documentation but what I am mainly missing is how in this scenario it can't be worked around. I wish the secure boot in stm32 was done properly with eFuses and the system bootloader doing the verification (say like a linux SoC or even esp32) and not so hacked around from my understanding.
From my understanding the way to prevent the DFU to boot would be:

Set options byte BOOT_ADD1 to point to my (or ST) secure bootloader instead of the ROM (system) bootloader
Set RDP (Readout protection) at level 2 which makes the options bytes read only, disables debugging and more goodies. Also this is irreversible so can't be worked around.

Is this understanding correct?
This is based on stm32h743 reference manual:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0433-stm32h742-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

I have used many of the STM32 families but not the H7.  Every one I have used -- once you set Level 2, it's permanent ("for good"), and the system bootloader is disabled.
For your H7, in the User Manual RM0433:

Per Table 24 (RM0433, ver. 8, page 186 in lower left corner): "No boot
from RAM or ST system flash memory in RDP level 2".

I haven't tried it, that's how I read it though.  Since Level 2 is permanent, I believe this disables the system bootloader for good.
Looks like an ST employee agrees for H7:  https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus/how-to-change-the-read-out-protection-on-stm32h7/ta-p/49411

Level 2 provides the same protection as level 1, but with permanent
protection by locking the option bytes. Once level 2 protection is
set, it cannot be undone, and the microcontroller will remain
permanently protected, the system bootloader is also unreachable in
this mode.


Similar behaviors in other families:

For the F4: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus/how-to-change-the-readout-protection-on-stm32f4/ta-p/49410 

> "Once level 2 protection is set...the system bootloader is also
> unreachable in this mode.""

For the U0: https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/index.php?title=Security:RDP_for_STM32U0&oldid=52720

> "RDP Level 2: The boot address must target the user flash memory. "



I am asking if RDP and setting the options byte provides a way to
disable the system bootloader for good

When you enable RDP (any level except 0) boot from system flash (ie bootloader) or RAM are disabled. Any Bootx pins and option bytes settings cant chage it.
You can reprogram flash from your application or bootloader (not the built-in one) when you set the protection level 2.
You need to write your own USB and programming routines to archive it. You can implement any protection of your firmware.
Normally I have an external FLASH memory where I keep the download and the last working firmware. After upload to the device, the bootloader checks the image integrity and if everything is OK it flashes the MCU.

I understand that, I am not asking if I can. I am asking if RDP and setting the options byte provides a way to disable the system bootloader for good

@UrielKatz updated
